# VBA - passing form field to a subroutine using ByRef

Tags: vba, parameters, arguments, subroutine, byref

Excuse lack of experience: In VBA I've written a subroutine that changes the value of a passed argument. This it does successfully for global fields, but not when passing, for example, a textbox on a form. I would expect the textbox to change but it does not. So for example (pseudo code):

```
Public Subroutine ChangeVal (ByRef abcde)
abcde = abcde * 2
End Sub

ChangeVal "txtabcde"
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your passing in a value but excel isn't going to know that this value belongs to any particular object.  To do what you want to do (assuming that your textbox is an ActiveX textbox with a name of 'TextBox1') you'd have using something like this:

```
Public Sub ChangeVal2(ByRef obj)
  obj.Value = obj.Value * 2
End Sub
```

And call it like this:

```
ChangeVal2 ActiveSheet.TextBox1
```